# Update data frame / table from data with similar structure

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data tables with similar structure (same number of rows same variables). I'd like to update the value in the first data frame using the values in the second, unless the values are undefined. Here is a reproducible example (using data.table, but the idea is the same):

```
library(data.table)

DT1 <- data.table(Categ = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  x = c(12,50,34),
                  y= c(5,2,8))

DT2 <- data.table(Categ = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  x = c(30,NA,NA),
                  y= c(1,NA,6))
```

My solution is rather simple, but is not scalable at all - if new columns are added, the code must be ammended. Also, it requires one row of code per column:

```
setnames(DT2, c("x","y"), c("x_new","y_new"))
DT3 <- merge(DT1,DT2,by='Categ')

DT3[!is.na(x_new), x:=x_new]
DT3[!is.na(y_new), y:=y_new]
```

Expected output, just to make sure I explained this right:

```
Categ    x  y
    A   30  1
    B   50  2
    C   34  6
```

Comment: Not sure if any better, but maybe ```DT1[DT2, `:=`(x = na.omit(i.x), y = na.omit(i.y)), on = "Categ", by = .EACHI]```?

Comment: @DavidArenburg - this works great. My data.table skill is not that great, but is it worth looking into using `.SDcols` ?

Comment: Not sure what for...

Comment: @akrun, yes, the up-voted solution using data.frames has the same issue! Not sure why it is up-voted.. Syntactically it's nice, but it has the same caveats (as I wrote under comment), and also assumes things.

Comment: By *scalable*, do you mean here in terms of writing many lines of code? That's confusing.

Comment: @Arun  You were spot on...  Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course we need to identify which rows for each column has NAs. There's no getting around it AFAICT. With that in mind, this is what was able to think of (a variation of @akrun's solution really):

```
# get DT1's matching indices for each row of DT2, handle multiple matches as well
idx = DT1[DT2, which = TRUE, on = "Categ", mult = "first"]
for (col in c("x", "y")) {
    nas = which(is.na(DT2[[col]]))
    this_idx = idx[nas]
    set(DT2, i = nas, j = col, value = DT1[[col]][this_idx])
}
```

This assumes identical column names in both data tables.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.frame`'s the following approach is possible:

```
# Convert to df
DF1 <- data.frame(DT1)
DF2 <- data.frame(DT2)

# Extract indices of NA values
ind <- which(is.na(DF2), arr.ind = T)

# Replace
DF2[ind] <- DF1[ind]
DF2
#  Categ  x y
#1     A 30 1
#2     B 50 2
#3     C 34 6
```

Comment: Wouldn't this copy all the columns (with any `TRUE`) as well? How is this scalable?

Comment: Perhaps not the most efficient, but answers OP's question imo

Comment: Not really. It assumes identical row-order. OP has used `merge()` (seems specifically to handle such cases correctly).

Comment: @mtoto - this works fine as long as rows are in same order. It does answer the question, however Arun is also right - not exactly the definition of scalable, but definitely more scalable than what I was doing.

Comment: I don't understand. Why is this definitely more scalable?

Comment: @Arun - because I don't need to specify the column names like I did in my solution. Meanwhile you posted your answer, and I do believe it is better - hence the upvote.